# Joomla theme only 1 page or module

Tags: css, php, cms, joomla, theme

Hi how can I theme only 1 page or module in joomla 1.5?
And I don't mean change the css but change the php file, so I can choose to display the date above the title and not below.

This should be very simple like in drupal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the frontpage? You wanted a single page to be frontpage like in www.envato.com? then it's easy. Just create a article and publish it in frontpage as article layout through menu. If that sounds greek and latin to you , please go download the yootheme Zoo app that comes with Page, Blog as the built in apps. You can move the date and time to anywhere using those apps. Create a PAGE and publish it via Menu

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this
I also know how to use template overrides now, but they are a little complicated for some modules
damn you joomla

Comment: So how has it been, did Zoo help you out. Was my answer helpful

Comment: zoo is a great module but it's a cck module, I got what I needed with some template overrides

Comment: @Ruben could you explain more i could benefit from you too

Comment: well, not easy to explain, I'll try. Let's say the customer needs to add an article with lots of html, it's better to use CCK so the customer only has to write text, not html, and the layout is generate by the CCK, like ZOO, but I use form2content. If you have an article section blog layout, and you want to change that layout, use a template override. Change something in templates, beez, html, com_content, section, blog_item.php.

Comment: Problem is, now you change all section blog layouts, if you only want to change one of them, you'll have to do some more coding. (stupid joomla)

Comment: lol did you know that , Zoo gives exactly the same needs as this. It comes with it's own content builder. You tell what comes where via a GUI and then the backend php hurles the code into those placeholders  more on here [zoo content builder documentaion](http://www.yootheme.com/zoo/content-builder)

Comment: I know but I have to use form2content because it's already implemented in the sites i'm working on and a simple template override is much faster than a custom content type. But yeah ZOO is very good and probably does it all I'm going to try it on my next website ;)